# PHP XMLReader read document fragment

Tags: php, xmlreader

Is there a way to handle XML document fragments with PHP's XMLReader?

There is this constant https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.xmlreader.php#xmlreader.constants.doc-fragment, however it seems to be never exposed to `XMLReader::$nodeType`...

Reading a fragment, e.g. `<frag /><frag />` just triggers a `Extra content at the end of the document` error.

As a side question... can the DTD be read too?
The constants `NOTATION`, `ENTITY`, `...` are also never exposed. Are these for internal use only or something, e.g. validating?

Thanks,

Roland